# My EC2 instance generates a keypair but unable to download into my downloads folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, public-key-encryption

I have launched ec2 instance successfully and created a new keypair. However, it is not in my downloads folder I only get to see the old keypair for the previous downloaded. I'm new to the ssh business side of things. it is driving me nuts.

any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Omar

Comment: Did you create a new keypair before launching? When you create a new keypair, you are given an option to download the private key. Did you download it?

Comment: to add to helloV's comment, you only get one chance to download the keypair. You cannot go back and download it again if you missed it.